# Is it on topic to ask about events not specifically covered in a book?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I read a book in which there is a short epilogue many years after the events of the main story.

I want to know if it is acceptable to ask questions about what happened in the interim.

As the book does not discuss those events the answers may be too opinion based. On the other hand sensible conclusions could be drawn from the information in the main story and the epilogue as well as factual ('real-life') information.

It would certainly be too opinion based to ask for instance if a character wore red in the interim. However my question would be far broader, for instance 'Did so and so likely partake in the war that happens in said interim?', this could probably be answered through character analysis etc.

Comment: If we were going based on SFF policy, then it would be yes, as 'we don't know'  is a perfectly good answer there.

Comment: @Mithrandir - "***We don't know***" is a fine answer, as long as you list off the places you checked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.

Answers may simply say why they don't know, or may give good-subjective answers in terms of general inference and interpretation based on the events in the book. A good answer to your question may be difficult to write if there isn't an absolute correct answer.

But that doesn't make the question bad - it could actually make it quite good. It does make it hard to answer, though.